# What is Offerman referring to with his Nazi doctor story?

Tags: plot-explanation, hunters

In the pilot of [*Hunters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunters_(2020_TV_series)), Offerman says to Jonah that "The Wolf" Wilhem Zuchs is the "Nazi doctor from his Auschwitz. The monster from my story."

What story is Offerman referring to?

When did he tell a story with a Nazi doctor to Jonah?

Comment: Why did you ask [one question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/110607/1) and then immediately change it to a completely different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“My story” is synonymous to “The story of my life”. Offer an could have just said, “My time in Auschwitz at the hands of the Nazis was horrific. The worst one was the doctor. Let me tell you my story.” Or, more simply, “I was in Auschwitz. Let me tell you my story.”

Comment: Got it, so this particular story was not told yet. I had expected that it was, because Offerman had told three (?) Auschwitz stories beforehand.